# Elixir, merging a new item into a list

Tags: elixir

new to Elixir and functional programming in general.  I am looking to merge a new item into a list of existing items.  When the "key" of the new item is already present in the list, I need to update the corresponding item in the list, otherwise I add the new item to the list.

I've come up with the below, but it seems a little clunky, is there a better way to be doing this?

Much thanks!

```
defmodule Test.LineItem do
  defstruct product_id: nil, quantity: nil
end

defmodule Test do
  alias Test.LineItem

  def main do
    existing_items = [
      %LineItem{product_id: 1, quantity: 123},
      %LineItem{product_id: 2, quantity: 234},
      %LineItem{product_id: 3, quantity: 345}
    ]

    IO.puts "*** SHOULD BE 3 ITEMS, QUANTITY OF 123, 244, 345 ***"
    new_item = %{product_id: 2, quantity: 10}
    Enum.each merge(existing_items, new_item), &IO.inspect(&1)

    IO.puts "*** SHOULD BE 4 ITEMS, QUANTITY OF 10, 123, 234, 345 ***"
    new_item = %{product_id: 4, quantity: 10}
    Enum.each merge(existing_items, new_item), &IO.inspect(&1)
    :ok
  end

  def merge(existing_items, new_item) do
    existing_items = existing_items |> Enum.map(&Map.from_struct/1)

    lines = Enum.map(existing_items, fn(x) ->
      if x.product_id == new_item.product_id do
        %{product_id: x.product_id, quantity: x.quantity + new_item.quantity}
      else
        x
      end
    end)

    unless Enum.find(lines, &(Map.get(&1, :product_id)==new_item.product_id)) do
      [new_item | lines]
    else
      lines
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FWIW I find your solution good if the output it gives is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the 3 great suggestions, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is quite close. It can be cleaned up in a couple different ways:

1. No need to convert from struct to map
2. You can perform the find first

Here is what I would do:

```
def merge(existing_items, new_item) do
  if Enum.any?(existing_items, &(&1.product_id == new_item.product_id)) do
    Enum.map(existing_items, fn existing_item ->
      if existing_item.product_id == new_item.product_id do
        %{existing_item | quantity: existing_item.quantify + new_item.quantity}
      else
        existing_item
      end
    end)
  else
    [new_item | existing_items]
  end
end
```

The map update `%{... | ...}` could be moved to its own function for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use maps for this.

```
map = %{
  1 => %LineItem{product_id: 1, quantity: 123},
  2 => %LineItem{product_id: 2, quantity: 234},
  3 => %LineItem{product_id: 3, quantity: 345}
}

# update existing item:
item = %LineItem{product_id: 2, quantity: 10}
map = Map.update(map, item.product_id, item, fn old_item -> 
    %{old_item | quantity: old_item.quantity + item.quantity} 
end)

# you can define a helper function so that you don't have to manually type the key
def upsert(map, %LineItem{} = item) do
  Map.update(map, item.product_id, item, fn old_item ->
    %{old_item | quantity: old_item.quantity + item.quantity}
  end)
end

# insert new item:
item =%LineItem{product_id: 4, quantity: 10} 
map = upsert(map, item)
```

[Map.update/4 documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update/4)

Then if you need items as list you can just

```
Map.values(map)
```

But of course with this solution you end up duplicating ids as keys.

Comment: Nope. He needs to add `quantity` when new item 's product_id already in existing map.

Comment: @YongHaoHu, oh yes totally missed that part. Edited answer using update

Comment: As for me, using a `external key` is strange.

Comment: @YongHaoHu, For maps, key lookup has O(1) complexity, while for Enum.find_index has to iterate all items in the worst case. And then you have to iterate through them again to update the value. So for large amounts of data map would be much more efficient

Comment: Yes. But if he want to use this `external key`, he can even use `product_id` as map's key, which looks good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have duplicate `prodct_id`.

Not changing your struct, I recommend using [List.update_at](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#update_at/3).

At first, use `Enum.find_index` instead of `Enum.find` to get the exist index(if there is)， then just update it.

```
  def merge(existing_items, new_item) do
    existing_items = existing_items |> Enum.map(&Map.from_struct/1)

    case Enum.find_index(existing_items, &(Map.get(&1, :product_id)==new_item.product_id)) do
      nil ->
        [new_item | existing_items]
      index ->
      List.update_at(existing_items, index, fn x ->
        %{product_id: x.product_id, quantity: x.quantity + new_item.quantity}
      end)
    end
  end
```